# iOS 7 BLE encryption / pairing

Tags: encryption, ios7, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a BLE peripheral that connects to an iOS7 device via JUST WORKS
We have control over the peripheral and the iPad App source code.

It is my understanding that in order to encrypt,  the peripheral it has to pair
Pairing causes the iOS 7 device to display a notification - "Bluetooth pairing request"

Is there a way to remove this notification so that the iOS device automatically pairs.

Note - This is not a question of Bonding.  I realize that if bonded the request will not happen.  We do not wish to bond.

Comment: You can't remove the Pairing request, it's part of the BLE stack & security protocols.

Comment: You can't remove it. However, if you can figure out how to disable security on your peripheral (the notification popped up as soon as it receive insufficient authorization error code, usually when you try to write on protected characteristic), then you are ok.

Comment: Agreed - notification is due to security on the BLE layer being added to the peripheral.  As a workaround we may have to do App level security instead of BLE level.